# how to set value to incremental variable name?

Tags: javascript

HI i got 4 flash clocks, that show the different city times, and i am getting the different 4 city times from my php file. after i get new time and minute and second for a city it sending me the information to a function like this :

```
 setFlashvar (hours,minutes,seconds);
```

so my function will called 4 times. now i need to send that 4 different parameter to my flash clocks like this :

```
flashvars1 = {thisH:myH,thisM:myM,thisS:myS};
flashvars2 = {thisH:myH + 2,thisM:myM + 2,thisS:myS + 2};
flashvars3 = {thisH:myH + 4,thisM:myM + 4,thisS:myS + 4};
flashvars4 = {thisH:myH + 4,thisM:myM + 4,thisS:myS + 4};
```

what is the best way to set this all variables with different times what i am getting from function?

thanks in advance.

Comment: it is still not clear **why** you want 4 separate variables. As long as you have those four objects, what difference does it make whether the values are in separate variables or in an array?  What do you want to **do** with the variables?

Comment: Overall it seem to me that you might know too little about programming to try to seek advice from the internet and that some person to person help might be far more useful.
But Pekka's answer is very well done, hopefully you understand it.

Answer (score 3):

Variable variables are bad practice. Use an array instead.

```
flashvars = new Array();
flashvars[0] = {thisH:myH,thisM:myM,thisS:myS};
flashvars[1] = {thisH:myH + 2,thisM:myM + 2,thisS:myS + 2};
....
```

(or use the notation demonstrated by @Pointy)

and then in the loop

```
flashvars[i]
```

Comment: Note that his original code is 1-based, so it's important to note that what used to be "flashvars1" will now be "flashvars[0]" unless a dummy entry is made for the start of the array.

Answer (score 1):

```
var flashvars = [
 {thisH:myH,thisM:myM,thisS:myS},
 {thisH:myH + 2,thisM:myM + 2,thisS:myS + 2},
 {thisH:myH + 4,thisM:myM + 4,thisS:myS + 4},
 {thisH:myH + 4,thisM:myM + 4,thisS:myS + 4}
];
```

Now instead of "flashvars1" you'll use "flasvars[0]".  (If you want to start at 1, then you'd just drop a `null` in before your first object value.)

Also, spaces are free :-)

Here's what your updated function would look like:

```
function setFlashvar (hours,minutes,seconds){
  flashvars.push({ thisH: hours, thisM: minutes, thisS: seconds });
}
```

That will add another object to the array. You don't need "i" because the array knows its own length.

Comment: i want to assign in to variable not in array. in case if i assign to array, that's not name of the variable. that is index no.of array right?

Comment: To assign to an array element, you'd just write `flashvars[1] = whatever;`

Comment: is it correct? is it possible to assign that array directly to variable like this ?

Comment: flashvars[1] = flashvars1 = {thisH:myH,thisM:myM,thisS:myS}; ? i am confused, help me!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - in that example I added to the answer, the function is using the array ".push()" method to add an object. Yes, it's possible to add an entire object like that to an array.

Comment: from array, how that will assign to variable?

Comment: @3gwebtrain I'm sorry but I just don't understand what you're asking. Maybe you should edit your original question and describe more about what you want the code to do.